# How to reload a UIWebView on HomeButton press

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I want to reload a simple UIWebView I have loaded when the app opens and closes from the iPad Home Button.

I've searched other questions, but none seem to fit as I don't want an extra button or Tab or something else in my app.

I tried:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [webView reload];
}
```

but this doesn't react. My initialization code is in a controller derived from UIViewController and the UIwebview is initialized in - (void)viewDidLoad

Any clue how to do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As people have pointed out you probably want the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` call but don't be tempted to add a load of junk to your app delegate.

Instead - you should register to receive this notification when you init the `UIViewController` that contains the `UIWebView`.

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(reloadWebView:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    // Do some more stuff
  }
  return self;
}
```

Then implement the refresh method something like:

```
- (void)reloadWebView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [webView reload];
}
```

You will need to unregister in your dealloc to avoid any nasty suprises something like this

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I tried to put your code in initWithNibName and created the function and deallocated it afterwards. But the app crashes on clicking the Homebutton with the message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebViewController reloadWebView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13e500'

Comment: Did you implement `- (void)reloadWebView:(NSNotification *)notification` I believe I may have corrected this method in my original response after you implemented it

Comment: no I didn't. Now I have and it works like a charm :-) BIG thx

Comment: by the way... what is the object:nil for? Does NSNotificationcenter require this param?

Comment: Have a skim of the docs for [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I believe it allows you narrow down which objects you want to receive messages from, if you pass `nil` then you will recieve message from any object posting a message with the name you supply.

Comment: What part of the above code goes in the viewController vs the applicationWillEnterForeground?

Comment: All of the code in my example is in a viewController. When the application is about to enter the foreground it posts a notification. The code above registers to be an observer of this notification so that we can then kick off our own actions.

Comment: I voted this up!!! I have about 8 hours of rl time looking for this. And while yes these methods are in the apple docs, said docs define them and not show you how to implement them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your view in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`.  This message is sent to your application delegate when the application resumes after having been put in the background with the home button.

Comment: same question as below, how do I reload the webview from the delegate if I initialize it in my WebViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to refresh the web view when the user resumes the app after multitasking? In that case, what you're after is the [applicationWillEnterForeground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground%3a) method in your `UIApplicationDelegate`.

General information on multitasking is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1).

Comment: I load my own WebViewController in both appdelegates for iPhone and iPad, so I only have one code for both. How would I access the webview in the appdelegate if it is initialized in my WebViewController